# Finding area between two polar curves using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I have a homework question that is asking me to find the area that lies:

- Inside the curve $r=2+cos(2\theta)$
- But outside the curve $r=2+sin(\theta)$

I think I'm supposed to be using a double integral to solve this (the chapter was on multiple integrals, so I don't think I should use the  $\frac{1}{2}\int thing $). For the region R, I think I should use $2+sin(\theta)\le r \le 2+cos(2\theta)$

So, for the final integral, I have:
$$A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{2+sin(\theta)}^{2+cos(2\theta)}rdrd\theta$$
I'm not sure what, but it seems wrong, especially since I don't really have an integrand (aside from the $rdrd\theta$). Would this be correct or what would I use?

Comment: Not having an integrand is fine - in fact, exactly what you'd expect from a "calculate the area" problem. In this sort of problem, you need to integrate the area element, which is precisely $rdrd\theta$. Your limits of integration seem to be correct. In general, if you're unsure of what the limits of integration should be, your first problem-solving step should be to draw a picture of the domain you need to consider. (Wolfram is great.) Actually, this is a pretty good first step regardless of whether or not you're unsure about the domain.

Comment: You'll find that what you get after carrying out the radial integration is just what you get in single-variable calculus with $\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{1}{2} \cdot [r_{outer}^2  - \ r_{inner}^2] \ d\theta $ .  We just never told you before that this came from a double integral...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much difference between doing area integration in polar coordinates as a double integral and in the way you may have encountered it earlier in single-variable calculus.  It is still important to have an idea of what the regions look like (here, you have a limacon and a "peanut").

Your radial portion is correct, but you really need to look at the angles where the curves intersect:  you'll want to solve $ \ 2 + \sin \theta \ = \ 2 + \cos (2 \theta)$ to get the range of angle integration. There are two zones to cover, but you can make use of symmetry here and just integrate over one of them.[image]

The red curve is the limacon $2 + \sin\theta$ , the blue curve, $2 + \cos(2 \theta)$ .

Incidentally, in the integral you wrote, it's not that there is *no* integrand, but rather that the integrand is "1".  You are doing a surface integral where all infinitesimal patches are equally "weighted" at 1 , so the result is simply the area of the region.  Surface integrals with some "weighting function" $f(r,\theta)$ or $g(x,y)$ turn up in various applications.

Comment: Ooh, okay. So, I solved it and got $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5\pi}{6}$. Can I set the bounds of the integral to this and multiply the entire thing by 2?

Comment: Note that there is a third intersection point from solving $2 \sin^2\theta + \sin\theta - 1 \ = \ 0$ , as the graph also indicates.  That point will be one endpoint of your angle integration.  (And, yes, you will multiply the area of one region by 2.)

Comment: Oh, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. So, $\int_{\frac{5\pi}6}^{\frac{3\pi}2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2} rdrd\theta$?

Comment: In your angle integration for one of these "crescents", you may want to use a range of either $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{13\pi}{6}$, since you are going to have to swing across the positive x-axis.  (Of course, you could also use $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ , going across the negative x-axis to avoid that issue...)

Comment: Just saw your comment revision now: I believe that should be good.  Happy integrating!